# navigation controller question

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i want multiple back buttons for the view i have click through , i saw this tutorial before, but now i can't find it anymore, can someone help me please

for example i have view1 with button, after i click it the navigation controller 
will push to view2 , then on the navigation bar we have view1 (back) 
button which can go back to view1, inside view2 i had did the same like 
view1 but this time is go to view3, and on the navigation bar instead have 
one view2 (back) button, i want to have view1 and view2 both button so i 
can choose which view i want to go back to

on view3 navigation bar left button will look this

< view1 < view2

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have a solution for you, but I wanted to mention that the User Interface Guidelines specifically discourage implementing navigation controllers this way.  In the iPhone universe, users are used to tapping the leftmost button on a navigation bar to take them to the previous view.  With multiple back buttons, tapping the leftmost button takes the user back to the beginning.  This may be a reason why this question hasn't been answered and may be a reason for the app no being approved.